# I want to show the name of the user logged in from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I making an Cafeteria App for my university where you can order food ,i Am able to send order from each user to firebase and am able to retrieve it successfully and send it to the admin of the App.But i am unable to show which user has ordered what.So is there way to retrive the name of the user who is logged in so i can send its AUD with the order.I am attaching screenshots of my firebase and firebase authentication page.I am able to display retrive data in both listview and recylerview,which one should i use to do above?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using email/password authentication, you will have to prompt the user for their name and store it in their user profile or somewhere in your database.  Firebase Authentication won't know anything about the user's real name until you do that. After that, you can attach their name to the order.

Comment: yes ik that,i dont want to display their name i want to display their AUD(thats our university id).And that is filled by each user and savedin database.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user's name like this.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

String name = user.getDisplayName();
```

And save it with order details.

Also take care of null name and promt user for name if it's not there in auth object like this

```
UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
.setDisplayName("Name of User")
.build();
 user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
```